# if end date lower than begin date so increment end date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two input fields to put begin and end dates. I would like to compare dates. If the end date is lower than the begin date I would like to increment end date with one month. I tried to do this but it doesn't work.

The dates are checked using calandar jquery ui

```
From: <input type="text" id="from" />
To: <input type="text" id="to" />



     if( ($("#from").val() >  $("#to").val()))
            {
                alert('end date should be upper the start date');
               $("#to").val()=incr_date($("#to"));


            }
function incr_date(date_str){
      var parts = date_str.split("-");
      var dt = new Date(
        parseInt(parts[0], 10),      // year
        parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1,  // month (starts with 0)
        parseInt(parts[2], 10)       // date
      );
      dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
      parts[0] = "" + dt.getFullYear();
      parts[1] = "" + (dt.getMonth() + 1);
      if (parts[1].length < 2) {
        parts[1] = "0" + parts[1];
      }
      parts[2] = "" + dt.getDate();
      if (parts[2].length < 2) {
        parts[2] = "0" + parts[2];
      }
      return parts.join("-");
    }
```

Comment: What part is giving you trouble?

Comment: this part :$("#to").val()=incr_date($("#to"));

Answer (score 1):

Assign the value inside the val() method like so:

```
$("#to").val(incr_date($("#to")));
```

You shouldn't need an equal sign.

**EDIT:**
See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/puddinman13/EDna8/) for a working JSFiddle. I used the focusout event on the txtToControl.

Comment: thanks but it still don't work ,i would like if i put 2014-07-01 in form input and 2014-06-03 in to input it show alert (end date should be upper the start date)and in end date input set 2014-07-03 (month+1)

Comment: I made some changes to your incr_date function in my JSFiddle. Please check the JSFiddle again. It should be working to your specifications now. One thing to note also was that this call incr_date($("#to")) needed to be incr_date($("#txtToDate").val())).

Comment: can you tell me what doing the new Date...??

Comment: Sure, read these http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date The tell you all about the javascript date function.

Comment: thank i undrestant but it doesn't resolve my problem, it still not working!!maybe because i use IE browser ???because it work fine in firefox

Comment: See the resolution to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327225/object-doesnt-support-addeventlistener-ie8-in-jquery When I tested in IE8, this seemed to be the issue. This may solve your IE compatibility problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper way to set  avalue:

```
 $("#to").val(incr_date($("#to")));
```